# strace has different result of Linux write system call on different buffer

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, embedded-linux

I try to write a data buffer into a file using `write()` system call on Linux, here is the user space code I wrote.

```
memset (dataBuffer, 'F', FILESIZE);
fp = open(fileName, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0644);      
write (fp, dataBuffer, FILESIZE);
```

I tried two types of dataBuffer, one is from `malloc()`, another one is from `mmap()`.

And I use `strace` to watch what the kernel will do on these two kind of buffer. Most of them are the same, but I saw when doing `write()`, they look different.

buffer from malloc()

```
[pid   258] open("/mnt/mtd/mmc/block/DATA10", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0644) = 3
[pid   258] write(3, "FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF"..., 691200) = 691200
```

buffer from mmap()

```
[pid   262] open("/mnt/mtd/mmc/block/DATA10", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0644) = 4
[pid   262] write(4, 0x76557000, 691200) = 691200
```

Like you can see above, the parameters of `write()` are different, one is "FFFFF..." like I memset before, but another is like a memory address.

Also the first parameter is different, one is 3, another is 4.

And on my system, buffer from `malloc()` is faster than `mmap()`.

How come they are different? Who made this different?

Thanks.

**Update**: how do I measure `malloc()` is faster?

I trace deep inside the `write()` in kernel, find out the last step of `write()` is `iov_iter_copy_from_user_atomic()`, I think this is the actual memory copy operation.

Then I using `gettimeofday()` to measure how long the `iov_iter_copy_from_user_atomic()` cost in malloc/mmap buffer.

Comment: How did you measure malloc() being faster?

Comment: @FrankMeerkötter I update how I measure the time

Comment: Isn't there an `strace` option that will show timestamps so you can see the time taken by system calls?

Comment: @Barmar yes, there is ,but in the beginning, I didn't plan to use strace to see the time cost, I already find the mmap() is slower, then I try to use strace to find out why it slow.

Comment: Use your strace output to check which syscall is actually used by malloc to do the allocation.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's checking whether there's a trailing `0` byte at the end of the buffer. If there is, it assumes the data is a string and displays it with quotes. If not, it just shows the address.

I can't think of a reason why the buffer from `malloc()` would be faster than `mmap()`. Calling `memset()` should get the memory of both into RAM, so the `write()` shouldn't have to wait for anything to be loaded into memory.